# Python sqlite3 sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: website even though column exists

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

database_connection = sqlite3.connect("accounts.db")
database_cursor = database_connection.cursor()


def create_table():
    database_cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (
        website VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
    """
    )


def create_account():
    website = input("\nEnter Website: ")
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    email = input("Enter Email: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")

    database_cursor.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO accounts ('website', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        VALUES (website, username, email, password)
    """
)


def remove_account():
    pass


def lookup_account():
    pass


def all_accounts():
    database_cursor.execute(
        """
        SELECT * FROM accounts;
    """)

    return database_cursor.fetchall()


create_table()
create_account()
print(all_accounts())

database_connection.commit()
database_connection.close()
```

[image: proof the column exists]

The code is untidy temp code (sorry) because i wanted to get the database to work, cant figure out why it's giving me this error. I'm very new to sqlite3 and sql so it's probably a dumb and elementary mistake but i cant get it to work. help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with this problem i troubleshooted a solution hope it helps :)

I Changed:

```
database_cursor.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO accounts ('website', 'username', 'email', 'password')
    VALUES (website, username, email, password)
"""
)
```

To:

```
database_cursor.execute(
    f"""
    INSERT INTO accounts (website, username, email, password)
    VALUES ('{user_website}', '{user_username}', '{user_email}', '{user_password}');
 """
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the db before you query it. You are doing this and passing it a table name as your db filename.

```
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn
```

here is the link for more info: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/

Comment: My database name is the same as the table but it has the .db file extension, also the fact it says that it hasn't got the column website i'm guessing that means its already connected? In the picture it says that the table is in the "accounts.db" database.